# how to change first loading view

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I got this code on didFinishLaunching but I don't know how to customize it to open up menuViewController from when I open the app.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:    (NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]] autorelease];
// Override point for customization after application launch.
self.viewController = [[[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil] autorelease];


self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
// At the end of applicationDidFinishLaunching, right before 
// the return YES
[[GCTurnBasedMatchHelper sharedInstance] authenticateLocalUser];
return YES;
}
```

hope someone can help me out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the following line

```
self.viewController = [[[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil] autorelease];
```

to

```
self.viewController = [[[menuViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"menuViewController" bundle:nil] autorelease];
```

Comment: yes already tried, lol just forgot to import it -.- Sorry guys thanks for the help anyways :)

Answer (score 0):

The line you need to change is

```
self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
```

To

```
MenuViewController *menuViewController = [[[MenuViewController alloc] init] autorelease];
self.window.rootViewController = menuViewController;
```

This is assuming you have a custom view controller called MenuViewController

Answer (score 0):

Create the object of `menuViewController` assign this controller to `rootViewController`.

```
self.viewController = [[[MenuViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"menuViewController" bundle:nil] autorelease];  

self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController; 
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```